# 2 separate groups of radio buttons in the same form WINAPI (No MFC)

Tags: c++, winapi, radio-button

I am looking to create 2 separate groups of radio buttons in a dialog box in my program but I cant quite get it to work correctly. As I understand it I need to be using the Group property but I am not getting the desired result.

I have 2 radio buttons that I wish the user to select 1 of, then a separate group of 6 which the user also selects 1 of.

Comment: Exactly how are you using the `WS_GROUP` style?  Post code.  What result are you actually getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have Solved the problem myself. Simply setting 1 of the radio buttons to true and leaving the rest false gave me the desired result. I didn't do this in code. I was just using the the properties view

Answer (score -1):

For instance, you have two groups of radio buttons. 
In order to make the first group you need write

```
WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP
```

The first group:

**`CreateWindowEx(bla_bla, bla_bla, bla_bla, WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla,bla,bla,bla);`**

`CreateWindowEx();` one more radio button which refers to the first group;(notice without `WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP` !!!!)

`CreateWindowEx();`one more radio button which refers to the first group;(notice without `WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP` !!!!)